# Converting a number to its equivalent in a specific range

Tags: algorithm, swift, math, logic

I have difficulties doing something, I want to convert a number to its "equivalent" in a given range.
Although the concept is really simple, it's pretty hard to explain so I'll do my best.

Let's say that you have got an infinite row of tiles, but although there is an infinite number of tiles, it's the exact same color pattern that repeats, like this :
[image: A row of coloured tiles, with the same color pattern repeating again and again. Each tile has a number.]

As you can see, I have given a number to each tile, but we could take a range, going from 0 to 4, and say :
0 is purple
1 is blue
2 is red
3 is green
4 is yellow

But because this color pattern repeats infinitely, actually, 5 will have the same color than 0, 6 will have the same color than 1, 8 will have the same color than 3.
Also, we must not forget negative numbers, -1 will have the same color than 4 for example.

Actually what I want to do is to convert any given number into a number of the range that I have choosen, here the range [0;4] so that I will know what colour corresponds to this particular tile.
I also want this method to work for other ranges, for example it should also work if my range was [1;5] or even [-7;-3].

I have already found a method that works for `[0;n]` ranges (with `n` a positive integer), and with `a` another positive integer :

```
convertedNumber = a % (n+1)
```

Here's what it gives with a playground :
[image: We are doing the conversion, which behaves as expected]

But it works only is the conditions that I described, and after hours struggling with it, I still can't find any good solution to make it work for any number, positive or negative, and for any range.

*Don't hesitate to ask for more details in the comments.*

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by range? if your given range is [1,5] ... here 1 still represents blue(as it is the first color) or red(as it is 1's original number)?

Comment: Maybe adding the difference between max and min to number, max and min will do the trick?

Comment: @karthik When I say a range, like [a,b], I mean all of the integers contained within a and b, with a and b included. So for [1,5] we will have 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: So for `-9` you want to return `1`?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise if your range is `[-7,-3]` and your number is `-9` you want to map it to `-6` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.  The function takes the number you want mapped, and the low and high values of the range and returns the value in the range:

```
func mapNum(n: Int, low lo: Int, high hi: Int) -> Int {
    let spread = hi - lo + 1
    return ((n - lo) % spread + spread) % spread + lo
}
```

Examples:

```
mapNum(-9, low: 0, high: 4)    // returns "1"
mapNum(-9, low: -3, high: 1)   // returns "1"
mapNum(1, low: -11, high: -7)  // returns "-9"
mapNum(3, low: -8, high: -4)   // returns "-7"
mapNum(-5, low: 4, high: 8)    // returns "5"
mapNum(-5, low: -6, high: -2)  // returns "-5"
mapNum(-9, low: -7, high: -3)  // returns "-4"
```

Comment: `((n - lo) % spread + spread) % spread + lo` is the same as `((n - lo) % spread) + lo`. The solution is correct though!

Comment: @HW, the extra `+ spread % spread` is there to account for negative numbers. In Swift, unlike C, `-7 % 2` is `-1` and we need the positive remainder here, hence the extra "dance". I don't use a conditional because calculations are usually quicker than a branch.

Comment: @vacawama Wow ! Your function does exactly what I wanted in an extremely simple way, thank you so much. I'll take time to understand the operations !

Comment: oh, ignore my comment then @vacawama - i assumed that swift uses the "usual" modulo operation.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise, the function works by using the modulo operator `%` to compute how far into the range we are and then adds that to the lower bound of the range to get the final answer. See my comment above to @HW for the explanation about the extra `+ spread % spread`.

Answer (score 3):

```
func modFromRange(range: Range<Int>, ind: Int) -> Int {
  let endIndex = abs(range.endIndex.predecessor() - range.startIndex).successor()
  let i = (ind - range.startIndex) % endIndex
  return i < 0 ? (range.startIndex + i + endIndex) : (range.startIndex + i)
}

modFromRange(1...5, ind: 1)      //  1
modFromRange(-7...(-3), ind: -8) // -3
```

Which works like:

```
modFromRange(-7...(-3), ind: -7) // -7
modFromRange(-7...(-3), ind: -2) // -7
modFromRange(-7...(-3), ind: -8) // -3
modFromRange(-7...(-3), ind:  1) // -4

modFromRange(1...5, ind:  1) // 1
modFromRange(1...5, ind:  5) // 5
modFromRange(1...5, ind:  6) // 1
modFromRange(1...5, ind:  0) // 5
modFromRange(1...5, ind: -1) // 4
modFromRange(1...5, ind: -9) // 1

For -7...-3:

[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7]
[ -5, -4, -3, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3]

For 1...5:

[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[ 5,  1,  2,  3,  4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4,  5]
```

Or, on Swift 2, you can do it as a method:

```
extension Range where T : IntegerLiteralConvertible, T : IntegerArithmeticType {
  func mod(ind: T) -> T {
    let _endIndex = {$0 >= 0 ? $0 : $0 * -1}(endIndex - startIndex)
    let i = (ind - startIndex) % _endIndex
    return i < 0 ? (startIndex + i + _endIndex) : (startIndex + i)
  }
}
```

Which would work like:

```
(1...5).mod(1) // 1
(1...5).mod(6) // 1
```

Comment: Your answer definitely makes me wonder why we can't accept more than one answer on SE. Love your example with Swift 2, I'll keep it for later, it makes it extremely easy to write what I wanted and works just as expected ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

```
extension Int {
    var convertedNumber: Int {
        if self < 0 {
            return  self * -4  % 5 + 1
        }
        return ( self % 5 ) + 1
    }
}
let n = -9
let result = n.convertedNumber  // 2


println(result) // 2

(-9).convertedNumber  // 2
(-8).convertedNumber  // 3
(-7).convertedNumber  // 4
(-6).convertedNumber  // 5
(-5).convertedNumber  // 1
(-4).convertedNumber  // 2
(-3).convertedNumber  // 3
(-2).convertedNumber  // 4
(-1).convertedNumber  // 5
(0).convertedNumber     // 1
(1).convertedNumber     // 2
(2).convertedNumber     // 3
(3).convertedNumber     // 4
(4).convertedNumber     // 5
(5).convertedNumber     // 1
(6).convertedNumber     // 2
(7).convertedNumber     // 3
(8).convertedNumber     // 4
(9).convertedNumber     // 5
(10).convertedNumber    // 1
```

Comment: Extensions give an interesting and modern way to write the code. Your code does nearly what I wanted, because actually, in my example, -1 should be 5, not 4. But thank you for the example.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise you just need to add 1 to the result.